# Create Table with Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, excel, oledb, oledbcommand

I would like to create an Excel table, using `OleDb`:

```
OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand();
oleDbCommand.Connection = oleDbConnection;

String commandText = "CREATE TABLE" + " [" + sheetModel.Sheet.Name + "] ";
commandText += "(";

for (int index = 0; index < spalten; index++)
{
    String _header = sheetModel.DT1.Rows[heaader].ItemArray[index].ToString();

    oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var" + (index + 1).ToString(), _header));

    if (index > 0)
    {
        commandText += ", ";
    }

    commandText += "@var" + index.ToString() + " VARCHAR";
}
commandText += ");";


try
{
    oleDbCommand.CommandText = commandText;
    oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    oleDbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    return;
}
```

The result for the Excel table is,

> @var0 @var1 @var2 @var3 @var4 @var5

but I should look like this:

> "PREIS/Stk. EURO" "Stk." "" "Produkt" "Artikelmerkmale" "Sonstige"

Where is my mistake?
The code is working fine for inserting values.

Comment: I don't know what your exact issue is right here... Is your main problem that the first line in your table doesn't contain the correct header captions (*Preis*, *Stück*, *Produkt* etc.) but *@var1-5* instead, or something else?

Comment: Where are you providing header captions in the string? you are just providing @var+(index + 1) in the loop.

Comment: @M463: Yes, you are right, that is my problem!

Comment: @learningNew: String _header = sheetModel.DT1.Rows[heaader].ItemArray[index].ToString(); // DT1 = DataTable with info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I created a table with the columns Name: F1, F2, ...

2) I Updated the columns Name with a dynamic Name (F1, F2, ... also created dynamicly)

```
String _Header = "PREIS/Stk. EURO"
oleDbCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE[MySheet] SET F1 = @var";
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var", _header));
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

As learningNew stated, you're just providing *@var+(index + 1)* inside your loop as the column headers.

To correct this, you could include an `switch` condition to provide the actual column header based on the current iteration cycle.

To do so, change the line

```
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var" + (index + 1).ToString(), _header));
```

to something like this (untested):

```
string colHeader = string.Empty;  // variable for the column header

switch (index)
{
    case 0:
        colHeader = "Preis/Stk. EURO";
    case 1:
        colHeader = "Stk.";
    case 2:
        colHeader = "Produkt";
    default:
        break;
}

// using the string variable here to set the actual column header
oleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(colHeader, _header));
```

Comment: Other question: Can I create a table without an column name?

Comment: I'm not firm with the OleDb syntax for creating a table in Excel, because I've always used the Excel Interoperabilty directly, as it allows for further interaction like accessing the markup of given cells. What happens if you provide `string.Emtpy` for a column header? I assume the code would crash, as missing column headers would mean missing field identifiers, which means your query would not know what column to fill the data in, but please correct me if I'm wrong here.