# OleDbCommand create excel column name with bracket

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbcommand

I want to create excel file by oledb, and my code is

```cs
int index = 0;
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{   
    datatype[index] = $"[{col.ColumnName}]" + " String";
    index++;
}

string query = string.Join(",", datatype);
cmd.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE [{sheetName}] ({query});";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and I have column name like `Product material[EN]`

I used break point and check my command string

```sql
CREATE TABLE [products] 
(
    [another Title] String,
    [Use of product[EN]] String,
    [Product material[EN]] String,
    [another Title] String
);
```

I've tried

1. `Product material[EN]`
2. `Product material[[EN]]]`
3. `[Product material[EN]]`
4. `'[Product material[EN]]'`
5. `Product material[[]EN]`
6. `['Product material[EN]']`
7. let all columns in query without bracket

```sql
CREATE TABLE [products] 
(
    another Title String,
    Use of product[EN] String,
    Product material[EN] String,
    another Title String
);
```

8. let all value in query without bracket

```sql
CREATE TABLE [products] 
(
    another Title String,
    Use of product EN String,
    Product material EN String,
    another Title String
);
```

but the above syntax all received `Syntax error in field definition.`

If using parameter and modify the code

```cs
cmd.CommandText = $"CREATE TABLE [{sheetName}] (";
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText + "[@var" + i.ToString() + "] String,";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var" + i.ToString(), datatype[i]);
}
cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Remove(cmd.CommandText.Length - 1, 1) + ");";
```

or change

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var" + i.ToString(), datatype[i]);`

to

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var" + i.ToString(), datatype[i]));`

and get the command string

```
CREATE TABLE [products] 
(
  [@var0] String,
  ...
  [@varN] String
);
```

will get a successful excel file but with `@varxx` column names

change to `Product material(EN)` is work but I need to use bracket `[]`

how do I add bracket into column name use oledb ?

Comment: Did it also fail without the brackets?

Comment: Normal columns in query without bracket cannot work, I'll update it

Comment: sorry, I missed the part where you wrote `Product material(EN)` was working. I had some doubt that the code would work because I am accustom to seeing `VARCHAR` instead of `String`. Have you tried to create the columns using Parameters? Perhaps this could help: [create table with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782085/create-table-with-parameters)

Comment: this code actually work before adding `Product material[EN]`, and I've tried parameter which is updated in article, is there something wrong with parameter usage?